# Android how to choose between nearby connections

Tags: android, connection

Im developing an app which uses androids nearby connections to connect two mobile units.

When I test the scenario with 3 mobile units, where two are advertising and one is discovering, it chooses to make a connection to one of them.

How do I generate a list of found endpoints instead so that the user can choose between them and select the right one to connect to?

My code is the following when an endpoint is found:

```
private final EndpointDiscoveryCallback mEndpointDiscoveryCallback = new EndpointDiscoveryCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onEndpointFound(String endpointId, DiscoveredEndpointInfo info) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"onEndpointFound",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        connect(endpointId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndpointLost(String endpointId) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"onEndpointLost",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Following the documentation https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/manage-connections it states "Depending on your use case, you may wish to instead display a list of discovered devices to the user, allowing them to choose which devices to connect to." But it does not state how to do this.

Comment: Just guessing: add endpoints to a List<DiscoveredEndpointInfo> as they come in, remove specific endpoints when onEndpointLost() is called for them. Show the List (in a ListView or RecyclerView) and refresh it if the List content changes